# Print blank space instead of integer from a 2D array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

This is homework, however this part isn't marked and I'm only doing it to make the output look nicer. I have a `2D` `3*3` array that stores all different integers from `0-8`. When I output the array, instead of printing out '0' I want to print out a blank space.

Here's my code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Can you just check for matrix[i][j] == 0?

Comment: that doesn't do what you intended to do.

Comment: Try `cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j]==0?" " : matrix[i][j];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is really trivial, just check for whether `matrix[i][j] == 0`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(4);
        if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        else 
            cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up slapping my forehead and answering it myself as soon as I posted this anyway, but I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks anyway buddy.